# Python Sqlite3 - Null as non-first element in tuple doesn't work

Tags: python, sqlite

I try to execute the following code:

```py
sqlcode = 'INSERT INTO ? VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
sqlparams = ('LOT', None, 'msg_number_1', 'descr_11', 'st_p_11', 'step_11', 'deposit_11', 'decr_pr_11', 'class_11')
cursor.execute(sqlcode, sqlparams)
```

I try to use `None` because of LOT table has active autoincrement at the first column.
But it doesn't work with the error message `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

If I try following code:

```py
sqlcode = 'INSERT INTO LOT VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
sqlparams = (None, 'msg_number_1', 'descr_11', 'st_p_11', 'step_11', 'deposit_11', 'decr_pr_11', 'class_11')
cursor.execute(sqlcode, sqlparams)
```

It works well. But why? I can't see any difference

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for the table name.

Comment: You can't use `?` to put a table name.  Only column values.

Comment: The rule is that you can use `?` wherever an expression is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you cannot use an expression like you would use for a value as a table name. The expression would be evaluated at runtime, which would mean the query could be run against different tables depending on the value of the expression.

And you're only allowed to use the `?` syntax where you'd be allowed to use expressions in SQL, for much the same reasons.

However, you can of course give SQLite a query for different tables from Python, as long as SQLite doesn't have to deal with the variable. For example:

```
table = 'LOT'
sqlcode = f'INSERT INTO {table} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
sqlparams = (None, 'msg_number_1', 'descr_11', 'st_p_11', 'step_11', 'deposit_11', 'decr_pr_11', 'class_11')
cursor.execute(sqlcode, sqlparams)
```

Or, if you get that tuple from somewhere else:

```
sqlcode = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
sqlparams = ('LOT', None, 'msg_number_1', 'descr_11', 'st_p_11', 'step_11', 'deposit_11', 'decr_pr_11', 'class_11')
cursor.execute(sqlcode.format(sqlparams[0]), sqlparams[1:])
```

But the previous solution is obviously preferable if you have control over `sqlparams`.